# Is the rank inequality true?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

rank$(ABA-CBC) \leqslant$ rank$(A-C) $?

Here $A$, $B$, $C$ are all $n \times n$ matrices for some fixed n. I tried to prove this so long. I do not know this is true or not. Any further suggestion will be helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true. Consider the following matrices:
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \cr 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix},\;
B=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \cr 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix},\;
C=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \cr 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then we have 
$$
A-C=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \cr -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix},\;
ABA-CBC=\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 \cr -1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}.
$$

Comment: Thank you @Dietrich. Do you know some inequality like $$rank(p(A,B)-p(A^',B)) \leqslant k \times rank(A-A^')$$ for some constant $k$ and $p $ is a polynomial in two variable?